# Does the sagemaker official tutorial generate an AttributeError, and how to solve it?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm following the [AWS Sagemaker tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-train-deploy-machine-learning-model-sagemaker/), but I think there's an error in the step 4a. Particularly, at line 3 I'm instructed to type:

```py
     s3_input_train = sagemaker.s3_input(s3_data='s3://{}/{}/train'.format(bucket_name, prefix), content_type='csv')
```

and I get the error

```
----> 3 s3_input_train = sagemaker.s3_input(s3_data='s3://{}/{}/train'.format(bucket_name, prefix), content_type='csv')

AttributeError: module 'sagemaker' has no attribute 's3_input'
```

Indeed, using `dir` shows that sagemaker has no attribute called s3_input. How can fix this so that I can keep advancing in the tutorial? I tried using `session.inputs`, but this redirects me to a page saying that `session` is deprecated and suggesting that I use `sagemaker.inputs.TrainingInput` instead of `sagemaker.s3_inputs`. Is this a good way of going forward?

Thanks everyone for the help and patience!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`sagemaker.inputs.TrainingInput`](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/utility/inputs.html#inputs) instead of `sagemaker.s3_inputs` worked to get that code cell functioning. It is an appropriate solution, though there may be another approach.

Step 4.b also had code which needed updating

```
sess = sagemaker.Session()
xgb = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(containers[my_region],role, train_instance_count=1, train_instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',output_path='s3://{}/{}/output'.format(bucket_name, prefix),sagemaker_session=sess)
xgb.set_hyperparameters(max_depth=5,eta=0.2,gamma=4,min_child_weight=6,subsample=0.8,silent=0,objective='binary:logistic',num_round=100)
```

uses parameters `train_instance_count` and `train_instance_type` which have been changed in a later version (https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/v2.html#parameter-and-class-name-changes).

Making these changes resolved the errors for the tutorial using `conda_python3` kernel.

Comment: Thanks! It works! Yes! It is necessary to change `train_instance_count` to `instance_count` and also `train_instance_type` to `instance_type`.